# How to select parent object of a hyperlink whose href match the requested page/file name using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to select parent object of a hyperlink whose href match the requested page/file name using jQuery?

I have following code

```
<div>
<div class="menu-head">
<a href="empdet.aspx">employees</a>
<a href="custdet.aspx">customers</a>
</div>
<div class="menu-head">
<a href="depdet.aspx">departments</a>
</div>
<div>
```

I want a Jquery to change the color of the parent div corresponding a hyperlink. If the user is browsing custdet.aspx the respective parent div background should be changed to red.

Edit: I have a method to retrieve the file name. I just need the right selector to select the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to post this over 2 hours ago and my internet died.  It just came back on so I'll add it to the list.

You can get the current path using `document.location.pathname`, to get the filename from the end `split()` on "/" and `pop()` the resulting array:

```
// get the current filename
var file = document.location.pathname.split("/").pop();

// get the parent of a matching hyperlink
var lPar = $('#menu-head > a[href="'+file+'"]').parent();
```

Side note: in your example you have two `div` elements with the same id (menu-head).  Duplicate IDs are invalid on the same page and you **will** run into issues if you do not make them unique.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('selector-to-get-your-nav a[href^=' + window.location.pathname + ']').parent().css('backgroundColor', '#FF0000');
});
```

window.location.pathname will prefix the path with a /, so either add a slash to the beginning of your URLs, do `window.location.pathname.slice(1)`, or change the selector from `href^=` to `href~=` to do a CONTAINS search rather than an equals (or change any of the [other selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) instead.

Edit: There is no selector to get the parent. You select the child, then use [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent)

Comment: It could be more than a `/`.  I was going to suggest something similar using `document.location.pathname.slice(document.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')+1)` instead of `window.location.pathname`

Comment: i have used following code to find the path. 
var sPath = window.location.pathname;
var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

Comment: @drs9222: Sorry.. I assumed his links were absolute. It depends how he fancies doing his links. If he was to have a link as `foo/bar/index.html`, then your example wouldn't work... swings and roundabouts :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#menu-head a').each(function() {
  if (window.location.pathname.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) > -1) $(this).parent().addClass('myRedClass');
});
```